# Android Popup menu showing scrolling

Tags: android, scrollview, popupmenu

I am show popup menu on image view click, some time it is showing all menu items and some time it is showing items with `scroll view`. What should I supposed to do. Because I have been not get any clue from documentation and I have also googled it. I know, some where I am missing some thing, but don't know. Below are images

[image: Image with scrolling effect]

[image: Image without scroll]

I want second one.

Here is my `xml` code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_card_item_copy"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_card_item_copy" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_card_item_rename"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:orderInCategory="101"
        android:title="@string/action_card_item_rename" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_card_item_delete"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:orderInCategory="102"
        android:title="@string/action_card_item_delete" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_card_item_export"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:orderInCategory="103"
        android:title="@string/action_card_item_export" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_card_item_commnent"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:orderInCategory="104"
        android:title="@string/action_card_item_comment" />

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is due to the screen congestion. Always popup menu shows top of the view or down of the view. If popup menu is don't have enough space, the scroll bar will come in the popup menu.

Comment: popup is also showing below the anchor, If the space is greater than upper.

Comment: In your xml, Please check with android:orderInCategory="100" sequentially(ascending order) in all views.

Answer (score 0):

> PopupMenu displays a Menu in a modal popup window anchored to a View.
>   The popup will appear below the anchor view if there is room, or above
>   it if there is not.

In your case, since there is not enough room to show the popup above the anchor(menu icon) & the space below the anchor is limited, it automatically switches to a Scroll view.

> **Some dirty technique by violating the guidelines** is to set the anchor
>   view of PopUpmenu to "do something" Imageview. Since ImageView is
>   above the menu icon, it will have more space below as the anchor & will show the entire popup.

Comment: there is enough space below. It is showing only for first row.

Comment: @FaisalAhsan In 1st image, there is no space left at bottom to show that last item.

Comment: there is only five items.. In second image they are showing perfectly

Comment: I want to remove that scroll same like second image.

Comment: When creating popupmenu, try setting the anchor of the view to "Do Something" Imageview. Its dirty but lets see if it fix your problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118419/discussion-between-sjy-and-faisal-ahsan).